# Cannot write on input field with Selenium Webdriver and Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec

I am still new to Selenium WD and performing remote blackbox tests in general. I am trying to input the email and password values into their respective fields to login to my page. I am able to navigate to the sign in page from home. However, not matter how many ways I write it, the console returns a failing test and an error saying 'element cannot be found.' This is the signin form:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-body">
      <h1>Log in</h1>

      <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
         <div class="field">
            <div class="form-field_2">&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <%= f.label :email %>&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="width: 50%; float: left; padding: 5px" id="email">
               <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
            </div>
         </div>
         <br/>
         <br/>
         <div class="field">
            <div class='form-field_2'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <%= f.label :password %>&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="width: 50%; float: left; padding: 5px" id="password">
               <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off"%>
            </div>
         </div>
         <br/>
         <br/>
         <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
            <div class="field">
               <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
               <br/>
               <div class="actions">
                  <div id="signin" style="text-align: center;">
                     <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-danger", id: 'submit' %>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <% end %>
                  <br/>
                  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
   </div>
</div>
```

My spec:

```
require './spec/spec_helper'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
feature "Signing in to ArtWare" do

before(:all) do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome)
end

it 'should let user in with a valid account and password' do
    @driver.navigate.to 'https://artwear.herokuapp.com/'
    @driver.find_element(:id, "signin").click  
    fill_in "user[email]", with: "email@provider.com"
    fill_in "user[password]", with: 'asdfasdf'
    @driver.find_element(:id, "submit").click
    expect(page).to have_content('Signed in successfully.')
end

it 'should let me logout' do
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    expect(page).to have_content('Signed out successfully.')  
end

it 'should not let use in with an invalid account' do
    @driver.find_element(:id, "signin").click  
    @driver.find_element(:id, 'user[email]').set('invalid@ainvalid.com')
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user[password]").set('asdfasdf')
    @driver.find_element(:id, "submit").click
    expect(page).to have_content("Invalid email or password")
end

it 'should not let user in with an invalid password' do
    @driver.navigate.to 'https://artwear.herokuapp.com/'
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "signin").click  
    @driver.find_element(:id, 'user[email]').set("email@provider.com")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "password").set('incorrect')
    @driver.find_element(:id, "signin").click
    expect(page).to have_content("Invalid email or password")
end

after(:all) do
    @driver.quit
end
```

spec_helper:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://artwear.herokuapp.com/'
Capybara.run_server = false

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

and Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake'
gem 'rspec', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.5.0'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.47.1'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.5.0'
```

This is the output that I get for the email tag in Google DevTools:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
```

I have tried to change the selenium call to:

```
fill_in "user_email", with: "email@provider.com"
fill_in 'user[email]', with: "email@provider.com"
fill_in :user_email, with: "email@provider.com"
@driver.find_element(:name, "user[email]").send_keys "email@provider.com"
@driver.find_element(:name, "user[email]").set("email@provider.com")
@driver.find_element(:id, 'user_email').set("email@provider.com")
```

all of these return the same error:

> Failure/Error: fill_in "user[email]", with: "email@provider.com"
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find field "user[email]"
>   or:
>       Failure/Error: @driver.find_element(:id, 'user[email]').set("email@provider.com")
>        Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError:
>          no such element

Could someone tell me what I am missing? I think I have gone through virtually every version that I have found in all Stackoverflow posts. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried it and this works fine for me:

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys("test@test.net")
```

only thing, I used firefox instead of chrome not sure if it behaves differently

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's the old issue wherein Capybara's searching by element id and not name.

If so, you'll need to ensure your input has the id it's identifying as missing (simply inspect the HTML or view source to verify).

Comment: I have tried using both name and id, but neither work. I have used the id that is rendered in the view source. I even wrote my own custom id to override the default, saw it rendered in the view source and called it on my specs, but it yields the same result...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same issue as OP's, but I wanted to mention something that fixed this for me: remove `autofocus: true`. I'm still not quite sure why this fixes it, but I think it has something to do with selenium and/or chrome and it's interactions with the autofocus field.